# Android - Change SimpleDateFormat template

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

Fairly new to Android/Java language; a lot of experience with obj-c.

Is it possible to alter the initial template given to SimpleDateFormat so you don't have to create a new instance each time you need to change it?

I ask because this is something I'm used to being able to do in obj-c. I've looked at the docs for SimpleDateFormat and didn't see anything there, but thought I'd double-check here.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve would be something like:

```
    // * I've excluded try/catch for simplicity

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM");
    sdf.parse(someDateObj);

    if (someDateObj==null) {
        // * setTemplate not real, 
        // * just example of what I'm trying to do...
        sdf.setTemplate("MM-dd-yyyy");
        sdf.parse(someDateObj);
    }
```

Is something like this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dnt thnk it is possible but why are you trying to set template when you have already formatted in sdf objct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`applyPattern` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#applyPattern-java.lang.String-) to supply a new pattern.

Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(sdf.parse("2014-10-17"));
sdf.applyPattern("MM-dd-yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.parse("10-17-2014"));
```

Output:

```
Fri Oct 17 00:00:00 PDT 2014
Fri Oct 17 00:00:00 PDT 2014
```

This method [appears to exist in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#applyPattern(java.lang.String)) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sdf.applyPattern("newpattern");
```

Comment: my bad. Hasty review.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the method is [`SimpleDateFormat#applyPattern(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#applyPattern%28java.lang.String%29) like

```
 sdf.applyPattern("MM-dd-yyyy");
```